# Breadth & Depth First Traverse Implementation

Tags: c#

I'm really struggling to implement these two methods. I've got the code however, just struggling to put it into practice. The `ref` is giving me an issue, I had it last time with `PreOrder`, `PostOrder` and `InOrder` but I used a `string buffer`. How can I get this code to work-

Here's the two methods

```
        public void DepthFirstTraverse(T startID, ref List<GraphNode<T>> visited)
        {
            LinkedList<T> adj;
            Stack<T> toVisit = new Stack<T>();
            GraphNode<T> current;
            toVisit.Push(startID); //push the first id onto the stack

            while (toVisit.Count != 0)
            {
                current = GetNodeByID(toVisit.Peek());
                adj = current.GetAdjList();
                visited.Add(current);

                foreach (T type in adj)
                {
                    if (!toVisit.Contains(type) && !visited.Contains(GetNodeByID(type)))
                    {
                        toVisit.Push(type);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void BreadthFirstTraverse(T startID, ref List<GraphNode<T>> visited)
        {
            LinkedList<T> adj;
            Queue<T> toVisit = new Queue<T>();
            GraphNode<T> current;
            toVisit.Enqueue(startID);

            while (toVisit.Count != 0)
            {
                //get it off from the list
                T currentID = toVisit.Dequeue();
                current = GetNodeByID(currentID);
                adj = current.GetAdjList();
                //add the current to the visited list, so we know where we have been
                visited.Add(current);
                foreach (T ID in adj)
                {
                    if (!toVisit.Contains(ID) && !visited.Contains(GetNodeByID(ID)))
                    {
                        toVisit.Enqueue(ID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here's my failing at getting an output-

```
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join, ',', myGraph.BreadthFirstTraverse(myGraph, ref 'a'));
```

I keep getting this error message -

A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

All my other methods work perfectly fine; `IsEmptyGraph()`, `ContainsGraph(GraphNode<T> node)`,  `IsAdjacent(GraphNode<T> from, GraphNode<T> to)`, `AddNode(T id)`,  `GraphNode<T> GetNodeByID(T id)`, `AddEdge(T from, T to)`. Just really wondering how to get this to work.

Please can someone help shed some light on this please.

I have the code, it's just about executing it all.

EDIT -
I just don't know what to pass into the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
myGraph.BreadthFirstTraverse(myGraph, ref 'a')
```

> A ref or out argument must be an assignable variable

You can't pass a constant as a ref parameter. If you *must* do this, the just create it first.

```
char youCanPassMeAsRef ='a';
myGraph.BreadthFirstTraverse(myGraph, ref youCanPassMeAsRef)
```

Comment: I see, I am still having a problem with the code. Now I have an error saying `C# Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ref Graph.Graph<char> to 'ref System.Collections.Generic.List<Graph.GraphNode<char>>'`

Comment: in that case you just need to pass something of the right type.

Comment: Yes, the constructor is  `BreadthFirstTraverse(T startID, ref List<GraphNode<T>> visited)`, the start ID I pass a char i.e. 'A', but the ref list doesn't make sense, within my method there is a list `LinkedList<T> adj;` but I cannot seem to call it.

Comment: You're better off posting a separate question.